# Android currency localization based upon download location

Tags: java, android, localization

We want to launch an Android app that captures currency based upon where the app is downloaded.

Of course we can get currency based upon device locale, but the issue is that many users around the world set locale as English (US) but the user could still be in india for example, but we don't want currency symbol to be dollar we want that to be indian rupee.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to get the Locale based on the Country Code which you can easily get from the `TELEPHONY_SERVICE` from the code as below:

```
TelephonyManager teleMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = teleMgr.getSimCountryIso();
```

Next, you can get the locale from the `countryCode` you get using the below snippet:

```
Locale loc = new Locale(countryCode.toUpperCase());
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: nice suggestion, but what if the user doesn't have a sim?